# SQL Duplicate Key Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I have a statement that looks something like this:

```
insert table_name(...)
select .... from ... join ...
```

How can I use where not exists or something of that effect with this insert and select statement so that if this exact code is reran with the same values, it won't throw an error. I don't want to have to copy and paste the select/joins in a check as it is a pretty big block of code, so is there any way to do something like

```
if not exists (insert table_name(...)
              select ... from...join)
```

or would it be something else like

```
insert table_name(...)
if not exists(select ... from ... join)
```

Comment: You could use [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) but it would be very inefficient unless you have some idea of the where clause that you can use in the right query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to keep this as generic as you did and still have it make sense. Hopefully, this is understandable.

```
insert table_name(...)
select .... from ... join ... 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                     FROM table_name
                     WHERE PKColumn = YourOuterSelectTable.PKColumn)
```

To try to put some more meat on it:

```
/* Assume Column1 is primary key */
INSERT INTO table_name
    (Column1, Column2)
    SELECT a.Column1, b.Column2
        FROM TableA a
            INNER JOIN TableB b
                ON a.Column1 = b.FKColumn1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                              FROM table_name
                              WHERE Column1 = a.Column1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the sql server MERGE command.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to just put it in a TRY CATCH block to just eat an exception if this insert fails.

http://geekswithblogs.net/ram/archive/2006/10/12/93829.aspx

On that note I must say that this is considered BAD PRACTICE to use exceptions to control logic flow.

I am more concerned about why this situation exists, I am having a hard time thinking of a legitimate situation in a GOOD DESIGN where this problem would occur?

Answer (score 0):

In your
select .... from ... join ...

do a left join to the table you are inserting to with the new values you want to insert

if those joined values are null then you can safely insert without error.